# close Matplotlib figure in each iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have a loop and need to show a figure in each iteration, I need to close the figure completely and after a while show another figure. This is my code:

```
 for j in range (3):
   img = mpimg.imread("E" + str(j) + ".jpg")
   imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
   plt.show(block=False)
   plt.pause(3)
   plt.close()
```

Here it seems that each figure will replace with another figure although I need the code to close the first figure completely, do some operations and then show another figure.I even used *plt.close("all")* but it didn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you exactly expect, but adding `plt.pause(1)` can have a similar result.

If your plt backend is Qt (you can check it via `plt.get_backend()` ), for absolute positioning of the figures, please use `plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.setGeometry(x0,y0,width,height)` function.
Additionally, if you want some operations to control the opening and closing figures, inserting `while` loop with keyboard input can be a simple soultion.

```
%matplotlib qt # Only if you are using Jupyter


import keyboard
import time

def keyboard_block(key):
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1.0)
        key_input = keyboard.read_key()
        if key_input == key:
            break
        else:
            print(key_input)

for j in range (3):
   img = mpimg.imread("E" + str(j) + ".jpg")
   imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
   plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.setGeometry(600,400,400,400)
   plt.show(block=False)
   plt.pause(3)
   keyboard_block(key='a') # wait before closing
   plt.close()
   keyboard_block(key='a') # wait before opening a new one
```

In this code, the first figure posp up for 3 seconds and it will close in 1 second. Then the second one pops up.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't work for me, the case is that I need not see any plt window for some seconds and then see another plot. plt.pause just pause the current plot for 1 second and then change it to another picture

Comment: BTW, I want to show my figure in the same position but in my code each time the position of the figure is changed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Which platform are you currently using now? Jupyter or CLI?